# Android - The Google Play services resources were not found

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am trying to show a map in my app with a feature to see current location. The app was working fine until yesterday but now I am getting this strange error

**The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.**

There are extensive answers to this problem here on stackoverflow and I tried all of them. I will be listing them down.

1. Copied (Imported) google-play-services_lib from sdk folder to my Workspace. and marked that as library with a solid green check mark.
2. Google Maps Android API v2 is turned ON in my google API console.
3. Verified my app package name with the package name in the API console.
4. Deleted the bin folder of my project and clean/rebuilt my project.
5. added raw value 4030500 instead of @integer/google_play_services_version in manifest
6. Crosschecked Google Play Services Rev. 15 is installed
7. Regenerated my API Key from console.

The only way I donot see the error is to remove  `googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);` this code. But I dont want to remove it because I want current location enabled.

Any new solutions?
Thanks!

Comment: But is your App crashed?

Comment: is it link mark error???

Comment: i faced the same in past but my maps working fine.

Comment: @MD No, The app does'not crash!. but on pressing current location button nothing happens!

Comment: @Nil No it is a Logcat error

Comment: then there is no issue about `google_play_services_lib`. issue in your code. post your code

Comment: ok then can you post code here??

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can remove all libraries and reimport them because sometime this libraries cause some problems in Eclipse projects.

You can follow this steps too. Visit https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2